# Can I filter one excel table based on the content of another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel files (actually, they are XML files, but commonly opened in excel by my users). They are just one table each.
The tables have an "ID" text column.

I want to enable my users to see the rows of each file that has no matching row (based on the ID column) in the other file.
Table1:

```
|Some words1| IdA | Some more words1|
|Some words2| IdB | Some more words2|
|Some words3| IdD | Some more words3|
```

Table2:

```
|Some words4| IdC | Some more words4|
|Some words5| IdA | Some more words5|
|Some words6| IdB | Some more words6|
|Some words7| IdE | Some more words7|
```

Since IdA and IdB occur in both tables, I wish to ignore them
Hence, I would like to extract

Table1_Filtered:

```
|Some words3| IdD | Some more words3|
```

Table2_Filtered:

```
|Some words4| IdC | Some more words4|
|Some words7| IdE | Some more words7|
```

Can I do this using just Excel features?
Alternatively, can I do it with minimal code?

I imagine that one solution would be to copy the tables into separate worksheets on the same Excel instance and expand both tables with a formula column that create a formula column that for each row checks the other Tables' ID column for a matching text.

Table1_WithFormulaColumn:

```
|Some words1| IdA | Some more words1|**True**
|Some words2| IdB | Some more words2|**True**
|Some words3| IdD | Some more words3|**False**
```

.... after which, this is a matter of normal excel filtering. I'm not positive what the VBA code would look like (I'm C#) , but I assume it is solveable.

Is there any other way? Or is this the best approach, and can you then show me what the code would be?

My users are using Excel 2013

Comment: If you have Visual Studio, developers are encouraged to use VSTO solutions going forward instead of VBA which gives you access to C#.

Comment: I have visual studio. The VSTO route would demand the users of the file installing an application that I provide, correct? I had hoped to solve this by posting excel instructions on the web site where the users collect the files.

Comment: That is correct, however, you can also develop Document Templates as well. Which would be specific to the document you create. Then, they can grab the template as they would the XML files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open both files in Excel and use a VLOOKUP to check if the value exists, wrap an If(ISERROR()) around it and you can return a true or a false.

If as above your data spans accross columns A, B and C you can use the following formula (adjust for each file).

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,<WorkbookToCheck>!B:B,1,False))=TRUE,"X","")
```

If the ID doesn't exist the the WorkbookToCheck then the formula will return X, otherwise it will return blank.